# Nutch Crawler read Segment results

Tags: apache, nutch, web-crawler

I crawled  using apache-nutch-crawler1.6. After crawling when i try to read the content of the  crawled result using the command 

```
 bin/nutch readseg -dump crawl/segments/* segmentAllContent
```

Error is

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/ubuntu/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-1.6/blogs/segments/2013062110/crawl_generate
    Input path does not exist: file:/home/ubuntu/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-1.6/blogs/segments/2013062110/crawl_fetch
    Input path does not exist: file:/home/ubuntu/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-1.6/blogs/segments/2013062110/crawl_parse
    Input path does not exist: file:/home/ubuntu/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-1.6/blogs/segments/2013062110/content
    Input path does not exist: file:/home/ubuntu/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-1.6/blogs/segments/2013062110/parse_data
    Input path does not exist: file:/home/ubuntu/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-1.6/blogs/segments/2013062110/parse_text
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:197)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:40)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:989)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:981)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:824)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1261)
            at org.apache.nutch.segment.SegmentReader.dump(SegmentReader.java:224)
            at org.apache.nutch.segment.SegmentReader.main(SegmentReader.java:572)
```

How would i read the html contents after crawling? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

I generally try to merge all segment first,

bin/nutch mergesegs crawl/merged crawl/segments/*

and then

bin/nutch readseg -dump crawl/merged/* segmentAllContent